# Evaluate $\oint_{C}(y-\sin x)dx+\cos x dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\oint_{C}(y-\sin x)dx+\cos x dy$$
>   triangle:$$C=\{y=0,x=2\pi,\pi y=2x\}$$

[image]

**My attempt:**

Using Green's theorem

$$\oint_{C}\underbrace{(y-\sin x)}_{P}dx+\underbrace{\cos x}_{Q} dy=\iint\bigg(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\bigg)$$

$$=\iint\bigg(-\sin x-1 \bigg)dxdy$$

$$=\int_{0}^{4}\bigg[\int_{0}^{2 \pi}\bigg(-\sin x-1\bigg)dx\bigg]dy$$

$$\int_{0}^{4}\bigg(\cos(2 \pi) -2 \pi\bigg)dy$$

$$=\int_{0}^{4}\bigg(1-2 \pi\bigg)dy=\boxed{\color{red}{4-8\pi}}$$

> Is it correct, area should't be $ \color{blue}{4\pi}$?

Comment: Your calculations are incorrect. You should be integrating over triangle, not a rectangle! Also, note that value of the integral is NOT necessarily area of that triangle.

Comment: so the upper limit should be $y=\frac{2x}{\pi}$? instead of $4$

Comment: Yes, but u need to change order of iterated integrals. Inner integral should be with repsect to $y$, and outer one with respect to $x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given

$$
\oint_C \Big( ( y - \sin(x) ) d x + \cos(x) d y \Big).
$$

Using Green's theorem, you should use $C$, so you get

$$
\oint_C \Big( ( y - \sin(x) ) d x + \cos(x) d y \Big)
= \oint_C \Big( P d x + Q d y \Big)
= \int_0^{2\pi} d x \int_0^{2x/\pi} d y
\left( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \right)\\
= - \int_0^{2\pi} d x \int_0^{2x/\pi} d y \Big( \sin(x) + 1 \Big).
$$

Work this out

$$
- \int_0^{2\pi} d x \int_0^{2x/\pi} d y\Big( \sin(x) + 1 \Big)
= - \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} d x \Big( x \sin(x) + x \Big)\\
= \frac{2}{\pi} \left[ x \cos(x) - \sin(x) - \frac{1}{2} x^2 \right]_0^{2\pi}
= 4 - 4\pi
$$